# File l3backend-pdfmode.def not found when loading expl3

Tags: packages, expl3

I updated my TeXlive distribution a couple times in the past week, and now I get this error when I include package `expl3` (or any other package that includes it, such as `fontspec`).
Before the updates it was working fine.
Am I missing any package that should be installed? I tried searching for `l3backend-pdfmode.def`, but I found no results.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

```sh
λ lualatex a
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.042 seconds
(/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.282   }

 379 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 dir, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 4 attrib
ute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:9,3:3,4:1,5:2,7:2,9:2
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on a.log.
```

Comment: The code has been moved to a dedicated package. Install the l3backend package.

Comment: That works. I tried to `tlmgr search l3backend` but I forgot that it only searches locally by default, and I did not find anything.

Comment: May I ask how you update your texlive? Whenever I update I also get all the new packages, and thus aren't missing stuff like this module split.

Comment: @daleif `tlmgr update --all`, possibly also `tlmgr update --self` if it complains. However, this was a minimal installation, so maybe that package should have been pulled in by some collection that was not installed (I am assuming, I am not sure how tlmgr works exactly)

Comment: That might explain it (that it was missing from a collection) as I always install everything

Comment: The only collections I have installed are `collection-basic`, `collection-langenglish`, `collection-latex`, `collection-luatex`. Every other package was installed manually. No idea what collections l3kernel and l3backend belong.

Comment: @Claudio `tlmgr info l3backend` says `collection-latexrecommended`, as I installed everything I got l3backend as an automatic install as I updated today

Comment: I'm running Texlive 2019 on Linux and I get the same error. The package is installed (I checked with `tlmgr info l3backend`). All packages are up to date and the only missing packages from my installation are those for Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Taekwondavide Do you get exactly "Missing l3backend-pdfmode.def"? Does that file exist on your system? `tlmgr search --all l3backend` should give something like `texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def`

Comment: @Claudio the error (from TeXstudio log) is `File 'l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found. }`. The file is present in folder `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend`.

Comment: The error has been solved by running `mktexlsr` as suggested by @Phelype Oleinik

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since the July 1st, 2019 release of the LaTeX3 kernel, the driver-specific code contained in the `l3backend` module was moved to a dedicated package in CTAN, and now `l3backend` is a dependency of `l3kernel`.

The description of [`l3backend` on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3backend) says:

> The func­tions here are de­fined dif­fer­ently de­pend­ing on the en­gine in use. As such, these are dis­tributed sep­a­rately from `l3k­er­nel` to al­low this code to be up­dated on an in­de­pen­dent sched­ule.

So if you updated `l3kernel` only without installing `l3backend` as well you'll get an error like this:

```
($TEXMFROOT/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-<driver-name>.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name:
```

and the solution is to install the missing `l3backend` package.

Comment: The package was already installed but I still get the error... I'm using texlive 2019 on Linux...

Comment: @Taekwondavide If `l3backend` is correctly installed the error should disappear. How did you install the package? What happens if you type `tlmgr info l3backend` in a terminal?

Comment: I downloaded and installed the full TeX Live 2019 distrubution from their website (I did not use Linux repositories). Everything worked fine until I updated all packages with tlmgr. If I type that command it says that the package is installed. If I open tlmgr GUI it says it is installed, the only missing packags are those specific for WIN32. I updated the package list from different CTAN mirrors and nothing change.

Comment: @Taekwondavide Did you update with `tlmgr update --all`? If you didn't, try it: it should update all packages and install missing ones. Does `kpsewhich -a l3backend-pdfmode.def` return something? If nothing works, I suggest you ask a new question, more people will see it :-)

Comment: I updated from `tlmgr --gui`. If I run `tlmgr update --all` it says that no updates are available. The output of `kpsewhich` is empty, however the file is present in folder `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend`.

Comment: @Taekwondavide Hm... try running `mktexlsr` to generate the filename database for kpathsea. Run `kpsewhich -a l3backend-pdfmode.def` again after that.

Comment: Thank you! I've run `mktexlsr` and this solved the error. Also, `kpsewhich` now returns the path of the "missing" file.

Comment: @Taekwondavide Great :D  I don't use the `--gui` much, so I don't know what it does, but apparently it didn't (for some reason) run `mktexlsr` after updating. `mktexlsr` generates the filename database which `kpsewhich` uses to locate the files in TeXLive. I imagined this was the problem after you said the file was there but `kpsewhich` didn't find it (just parroting for future readers: I'm afraid this problem will keep happening for some time :-).

Comment: I didn't find `l3backend` package. For me what solved it is to install `l3kernel` (miktex did it automatically when I did check for updates).

Comment: I reinstalled both l3backend and l3kernel and I still have the same error. I am running Windows and MikTeX. Same error appears both on TeXStudio and LyX. Please help!!

Comment: @Kasra Sorry, I don't use MiKTeX, so I won't be able to help you much.  Please, [ask a new question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), so some MiKTeX experts may help you

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik. I looked all over the internet and NO answer. I gave up on MiKTeX (possibly forever). I switched to TeXLive and everything works fine now!

Comment: @Kasra As I said, you could have asked a question (even though I also very much prefer TeX Live over MiKTeX :).  Glad to know it's working!

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik. It was asked before so I tried not making duplicate question.  [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564606/file-l3backend-pdftex-def-not-found-even-after-installing-l3backend/580627#580627)

Answer (score 55):

For Windows:

1. Open the MikTeX Console
2. Check for Update
3. Updates > Update Now
4. Search l3backend package
5. Install the package

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for. :D

Comment: Solved it for me perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: When I update, I get `something went wrong while checking for update`. `Invalid argument: path="C:\Users\id917977\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb"`

Comment: Does adding `\usepackage{l3backend}` to the preamble of your document tell MikTeX what it should be looking for to avoid manual package installation?

Comment: Similar process for Mac (High Sierra): 
1. Press CMD + Space Bar to search
2. Serach & Open MikTeX Console
3. Click "Reopen as Administrator"
4. Check for Updates
5. Updates > Update Now.


I personally didn't need to install anything additional.

Answer (score 0):

For MikTeX under Linux (Ubuntu), all that is required to

1. `sudo miktex-console`
2. Choose `Switch to MiKTeX administrator mode`
3. Choose `Check for updates` under `Updates`.

MiKTeX will automatically install `l3backend` and other missing packages when needed.