# File l3backend-pdfmode.def not found when loading expl3 alternative solution

Tags: packages, expl3

I have a problem compiling documents - if I use `expl3` package, I get an error `l3backend error` saying `` ! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found. `` My problem is that installing `l3backend` package (as suggested as an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499082/file-l3backend-pdfmode-def-not-found-when-loading-expl3)) does not resolve the problem. I tried installing the package the same way as all my packages - using `\usepackage{l3backend}` in my document like this

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3backend}

\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

I get no windows asking me for package installation permission as I usually do when including a new package and I keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: install the l3backend package with the package manager of your tex system.

Comment: your mention of a "window" probably means that you are using miktex. In this case update the package data base in the miktex console. There is an icon "Update DB" above the list of packages.

Comment: And you should never `\usepackage{l3backend}`. The correct backend package is selected automatically by `expl3`: loading it manually will usually be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Ulrike's comment.

> In this case update the package data base in the miktex console. There is an icon "Update DB" above the list of packages.

And also deleted `\usepackage{l3backend}` from my code as Phelype suggested. That solved it. Thanks

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, it's fine to mark it as accepted even if you posted it yourself. This question then won't show up in the list of unanswered questions anymore.

Comment: I would, but it is only possible to accept my own answer after a period of 2 days since I posted it. That is why it's unmarked yet.