# ! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found

Tags: packages

I am facing the same error : ! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found. I have seen some comments mentioning to go to the "Update DB" option in the miktex console. But I am not able to find it. Can anyone help me with a screenshot of how to find this option ? Would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/134574) has detailed step-by-step instructions on how to hupdate with MiKTeX.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499082/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499252/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Update DataBase" option is a little bit hidden in MiKTeX Console.

1. Just open MiKTeX Console
2. Choose if you need admin or user mode (depends on your installation). Because I have an admin installation I choosed Admin mode ...
3. Click on menu point "Tasks" (near "File", see red circle in the screenshot ...)
4. Click on "Update Package Database" to update the database for available packages with MiKTeX (see red arrows in screenshot ...)
5. Use this opportunity and click afterwards on "Refresh file name data base" ...

Please see this screenshot:

[image: MiKTeX Console Tasks]

For the ususal way to update your MiKTeX follow [how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

I had recently updated from Debian 10 to Debian 11  when I started to get this error. Among other things, I tried purging and reinstalling my whole `texlive`-related packages, but this was producing no effects.

For me, removing all the `.texlive*` folders from my home directory did the trick. If you are in the same boat as me, then

```
mv ~/.texlive* /tmp # For security reasons
rm -r ~/.texlive* # If you are really sure
```

should clear the issue. Once I did that and run `pdflatex`, the `~/.texlive2020` directory was rebuilt, and `pdflatex` started to work again without a flaw.