# MiKTeX Linux Docker : LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def' not found

Tags: miktex, linux

I have a Docker container and installed MiKTeX, but when I try to generate a PDF, I get an error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def' not found.
```

Here is the Docker file:

```
FROM node:12.6.0-stretch

COPY fix-proxy-apt /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy
RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
RUN echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/debian stretch universe" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
RUN apt update && apt install -y git miktex bash
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./

RUN rm -rf ./node_modules
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
COPY backend.sh /backend.sh
RUN chmod +x /backend.sh

RUN miktexsetup --shared=yes finish
RUN initexmf --admin --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1

ENTRYPOINT ["/backend.sh"]
```

From what I understand the following line:

```
RUN initexmf --admin --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1
```

should install missing package, however I still get the error.

I've found this post:
[File l3backend-pdfmode.def not found when loading expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499082/file-l3backend-pdfmode-def-not-found-when-loading-expl3)

So I tried to add the following line to my dockerfile:

```
RUN tlmgr update --all
```

However `tlmgr` is not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `tlmgr` is from TeXLive. For MiKTeX see the second answer to the post you linked (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499414/134574).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really help since the prodcedure is for windows.

Comment: the package database is probably outdated (l3backend is quite new) and so miktex doesn't know in which package the missing file is. In windows I would update the database on the command line with `mpm --update-db` but I have no idea how this is done in your setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to the Docker file resolved  my issue.

```
# update file name database
RUN initexmf --update-fndb --admin
# build the font maps
RUN initexmf --mkmaps --admin
# create all possible links
RUN initexmf --mklinks --force --admin
# Check the package repository for updates, then print the list of updateable packages.
RUN mpm --find-updates --admin
# Update all installed packages.
RUN mpm --update --admin
```

Comment: I got same error, What is docker file? where can I find it

Comment: Dockerfile is a file for docker containers, if you aren't using docker to run miktex you can just use the commands mentionned in the answer w/o the RUN before them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MiKTeX, go to `MiKTeX Console` → `Check for updates` → `Install`.