# ! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found (in line)

Tags: packages, lists, enumerate

I have modified some details in the text of the file and now I am getting this error. I already installed the corresponding package and nothing ... :(

The error occurs on the line below:

\item $p \to q \,\vdash\,  (p \to q) \, \vee  \sim r $

Full Code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z27i6UkOAugZBIUpB465lgM9Hxp4cDe9

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499082/134574?

Comment: It should be enough to install the [`l3backend`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3backend) package through your TeX distribution's package manager (TeX Live's `tlmgr` or MikTeX Console, make sure to update all installed packages as well, if you are using a mutli-user MikTeX installation update in both Admin *and* User mode). For future questions please don't link to external download sites for the full code example, instead provide a *small* example document directly in the question (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).