# How can I update l3backend-pdftex.def, if MiKTeX says it is updated when TeXWorks does not agree?

Tags: pdftex

I am re-compiling a document I haven't compiled in a while.

I updated all the packages and I am getting this error message:

> ! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
> Loading 'l3backend-pdftex.def' aborted!
>
> The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
> is dated 2020-09-03, but in your TeX tree the files require
> at least 2021-02-18.

the "l3backend" package is installed and up-to-date. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it. I have located the files and on line 29 I find:

> {l3backend-pdftex.def}{2022-10-26}{}

so it should fulfil the requirement (as far as I understand).

I have read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564606/27256), but if possible I'd like not to switch out of MiKTeX.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: texworks is just your editor and does not load the file at all, make sure you updated miktex in both user and admin mode

Comment: What does `kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` report?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "major issue: user/administrator updates are out-of-sync" uuuuh.... how do I fix this?

Comment: as David wrote: check for update in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: Update miktex in both miktex user and miktex admin mode.

Comment: if anyone wants to turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed miktex in multi-user mode ("for all users") it typically has a texmf tree for all users and a texmf tree for every user account which contains packages that this user installs "only for me" (e.g. through the on-the-fly option). It is then important that you maintain miktex in admin mode ("for all users") *and* user mode ("for you only") to avoid that the two trees get out of sync.

So always check for updates in both modes.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=62248781#62248781