# How can I install l3backend-pdfmode.def?

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

When I try to compile a .tex file with no additional \usepackage, I get the following error:

> LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.

Following [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499082/file-l3backend-pdfmode-def-not-found-when-loading-expl3) I ran `tlmgr update --all` and `tlmgr update --self`, but I still got the error. I noticed that there is no `l3backend-pdfmode.def` in the directory `l3backend`:

> C:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\tex\latex\l3backend
> 2020/10/16  18:54              .
> 2020/10/16  18:54              ..
> 2020/10/16  16:13            24,777 l3backend-dvipdfmx.def
> 2020/10/16  16:13            32,860 l3backend-dvips.def
> 2020/10/16  16:13            17,860 l3backend-dvisvgm.def
> 2020/10/16  16:13            24,060 l3backend-luatex.def
> 2020/10/16  16:13            23,704 l3backend-pdftex.def
> 2020/10/16  16:13            26,739 l3backend-xetex.def

I am guessing that I have to add `l3backend-pdfmode.def' manually, but how can I do that?

Comment: you have an old latex format that is still looking for the old name possibly a local one that is masking the one installed by your update, you should be able to delete it.

Comment: If pdf mode is searched you probably have an old local format somewhere. Check with kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt

Comment: Deleting pdflatex.fmt worked! Thank you so much.