# File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found (TeX Live 2020)

Tags: luatex, latex3, texlive-2020

I just finished installing and updating TeX Live 2020 on Windows 10. I performed a full installation of TeX Live. Now, compiling this simple document:

```tex
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

I receive this error message:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(c:/Users/marco/Downloads/temp/temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
Calling deprecated Lua function strcmp (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2020/10/04 v3.7n configurable book, report, article document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty))

! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: something it not up-to-date. check for updates and check if you have some local format hiding the system formats.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499082/file-l3backend-pdfmode-def-not-found-when-loading-expl3

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I run `tlmgr update -all`, I receive this message: ‘tlmgr.pl: no updates available’. If I run `tlmgr update --self`, I receive this message: ‘tlmgr.pl: no self-updates for tlmgr available’. And `tlmgr search l3backend` returns ‘l3backend - LaTeX3 backend drivers’. How can I check about the formats?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had seen that answer before. However it doesn’t solve my problem. Could a fresh installation from scratch be the solution?

Comment: `kpsewhich --all  -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` probably reports two formats

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that returns: c:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt. What does it mean?

Comment: I just re-installed TeX Live 2020 from scratch (using the ISO file). I only updated TeX Live Manager, but not the packages. Now the document compiles without generating errors. The question now is: if I update the packages, will it continue to work without problems?

Comment: @Marco87 that's the correct output (quite often it returns two pdflatex.fmt in two locations which is bad as often the updates update the standard one but pdflatex keeps finding an old format in a local input directory that was my guess here but not the case so that is good)

Comment: After updating with `tlmgr update --all`, the compilation ends without any error. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue after a recent `tlmgr update --all` with texlive 2020. Reinstalling l3backends, l3kernel didn't help.

The changelog for l3backends reads:

> ### [2020-09-01]
>
> #### Changed
>
> ...
>
> - Split `pdfmode` driver into pdfTeX- and LuaTeX-specific  files
>   ...

so, evidently my recent update picked up this change (it's been a while since I updated).

Then I noticed that when running pdflatex I get:

> LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
> L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>

So an old L3 version (which preceds the change to l3backend change) is being used, even though L3 had supposedly just been updated to something more recent.

Just as an extra data point, I also noticed that xetex didn't seem to have similar issues.

Following the comment by @David_Carlisle, I ran `kpsewhich --all  -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` and found that I have two locations reported on my system:

> /home/craig/.texlive2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
> /home/craig/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt

I renamed the first one, and the problem went away.

Some related issues suggested that you may need to run `mktexlsr`, though I didn't need to.

Good luck.

Comment: I see exactly the same issue. I just install a new fresh TexLive 2020, and update all the packages. Then, I see the same issue when compiler a minimal tex file. If I run the pdflatex, I got the `l3backend-pdfmode.def` not found issue, if I run pdfxelatex, I got the `l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def` not found issue. I have tried your method, and `kpsewhich --all  -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt ` only returns one location. So, not sure how to fix this issue. Thanks.